# measure the fit of two distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, sampling

The population of a county is 150,000, ages and sexes are known. Somebody selected a sample of 2,000 people, the selection rules are not quite clear but the age and sex distributions are given. My objective is to find out what selection rules were used. I built a model which does this, and have my own sample of about the same size. The age and gender profiles are close to the original sample, but the fit is less than 100% perfect. I'd like to assess the quality of fit, for example, estimate the probability that a randomly selected sample would be as close to the original one as mine. The trouble is I do not know how to do this. Could you help?

Comment: Is your notion of “close” having the same joint distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's just look at age groups. Suppose there are five groups and that
the population proportions are given by vector `pr=(.2, .2, .3, .2, .1)`.

Take two samples of size $2000,$ very much smaller than the population.

```
set.seed(902)
pr = c(.2,.2,.3,.2,.1)
x1 = sample(1:5, 2000, rep=T, p = pr)
x2 = sample(1:5, 2000, rep=T, p = pr)
```

There are relatively small differences in category counts between the tow samples.
However, treating categories as nominal, a chi-squared test finds no
significant difference between the two samples at the 5% level.
The P-value $0.55 > 0.05 = 5\%$ of the test is probability of a worse fit (according to the chi-squared
criterion, comparing observed and expected counts.).

```
t1 = tabulate(t1);  t2 = tabulate(t2)
TBL = rbind(t1,t2);  TBL
t1 = tabulate(x1);  t2 = tabulate(x2)
TBL = rbind(t1,t2);  TBL
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
t1  408  390  624  371  207
t2  412  366  637  399  186

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 barplot(t1, names.arg=1:5, xlab="Sample 1", col="skyblue2")
 barplot(t2, names.arg=1:5, xlab="Sample 2", col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
chisq.test(TBL)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 3.0558, df = 4, p-value = 0.5485
```

In the figure below, the vertical dotted line is at the chi-squared statistic. The area under the density curve to the right of that line
is the P-value of the test.

[image]

---

Treating the age categories as ordinal, a Wilcoxon rank sum
test finds no significant difference in the locations of the two
samples.

```
wilcox.test(x1,x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 1994000, p-value = 0.8668
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

However, I know of no test that looks at your desired "probability that a randomly selected sample would be as close to the original one as mine."
I don't know your purpose in comparing the two samples. Perhaps a better question is whether *for practical purposes* there is an **important** difference
in counts between the two. That is a judgment call---IMHO not a statistical question.

*Notes:* (1) You could test whether your Sample 2 is a bad match for the
population proportion. Of course, your sample is very unlikely to be
an *exact* match to the population proportion, but as long as you use
random sampling, the P-value will tend to be above $0.05,$ sometimes just barely, sometimes greatly, and (of course about $5\%$ of the time) below $0.05.$ [Because the chi-squared statistic, which depends on counts, is discrete, the distribution of the P-value under $H_0$ will not be *exacty* uniform in $(0,1).]$

```
chisq.test(t2, p = pr)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  t2
X-squared = 6.5142, df = 4, p-value = 0.1639


    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  t2
X-squared = 6.5142, df = 4, p-value = 0.1639
```

(2) While some chi-squared tests are often called "goodness-of-fit" tests, but they reject 'fit' when the chi-squared statistic is large
and we *reject* when the chi-squared statistic is *large* (and P-value is small). So it might be better to call these chi-squared statistics "badness-of-fit" statistics--the larger the statistic, the worse the fit.

Comment: Thank you very much, the chi-squared test must be the right approach. My only remaining problem is the interpretation of the results. In your example, the p-value was 0.55; could you please explain what this means? What was the null hypothesis?

Comment: Null hypothesis of chi-sq test is that the counts in the sample are consistent with the probabilities in the population. The P-value is the probability of getting a chi-squared statistic at least as large as observed (assuming $H_0$ true). Large values of the chi-sq statistic lead to small P-values. If P-val < 5% then Reject at 5% level. In R code `1 - pchisq(3.0558, 4)` returns  $0.5485312.$  So null hypothesis not rejected--not even close to rejection.. // See added figure. If the chi-squared statistic were greater than  9.488, then the null hypothesis would have been rejected.

Comment: Thank you. I performed this test for my sample, and got the following results. First, for the two samples, the original one and the one created by my model: X-squared = 10.63, df = 13, p-value = 0.6418. Then, for my sample and the original population scaled to the same size: X-squared = 1620.5, df = 13, p-value < 2.2e-16. Can I interpret this as an indication that: 1) the difference between the two samples is not statistically significant and 2) the age distributions in the model sample and the entire population are significantly different?

Comment: Yes. Good work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My only remaining concern is that not rejecting the hypothesis that the two samples are consistent is not quite the same as proving that they are. Is there a way to test the alternative null hypothesis, the one that the samples are different?

Comment: You shouldn't look for "proof" in hypothesis testing. Roughly, frequentist hypothesis testing goes like this: ff we test a null hypothesis, we assume for the moment that it is true, and then ask if our data would likely have occurred under that assumption. If the answer is clearly No (tiny P-value) , then the hypothesis is rejected, if the answer is possibly Yes then it seems reasonable to believe the hypothesis may be true (at least until additional data are available)).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand the logic of testing now.

Comment: Yet there is something in chi-squared I still can't figure out. If I scale my dataset up, say multiply each value by a hundred, X-squared goes up, P-values go down so that H0 does not hold anymore. Yet the distribution remained the same, effectively I only changed the unit of measurement. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Don't 'scale' counts. There is a huge difference between 4 Heads in 10 tosses (which is consistent with a fair coin), and 400 Heads in 1000 tosses (which is overwhelming evidence to reject 'fairness'.)// In R, code `pbinom(4, 10, .5)` returns $0.3769531$ (not unlikely), whereas code `pbinom(400, 1000, .5)` returns $1.364232e-10$ (less than one chance in a billion).

Comment: OK, I got it! I also read your comment on the same question, very useful, thank you. What about scaling down then? If I want to prove that my model is a better fit to the target than the original population from which I made my selection, I need to scale the population distribution down to the size of my model. Is this comparison still meaningful statisticaslly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'm wary about any kind of scaling for count data.

Comment: There is a fairly large population from which somebody selected a sample. The selection rules are unknown so I built a model to replicate this selection. I use chi-square to show that my selection is statistically consistent with the original sample. In addition, I'd like to show that both the original selection and my model, which are similar, are still very different from the entire population. I want to do a chi-square test again, but this would probably require making a version of the population of the same size as my model.